# Include node module in a standard JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to include a node module into a standard javascript file using:

```
const swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

But this doesn't work, and when i later use the package to do things, it says swal is not defined. I've tried including it with a script tag in my html which also failed:

```
<script type="module" src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

that was in the html file that calls the function from the javascript file. Any help on how i can include this package would be greatly apreciated

Comment: Your environment is a browser or node.js? Because node.js don't has `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use modules installed by `npm install` in browser, use something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or webpack.

Or use a valid URL

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.29.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2?path=dist

Answer (score 0):

Install npm module `npm i sweetalert2 --save`

Try this way to add in js file

```
// ES6 Modules or TypeScript
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

// CommonJS
const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
```

For more info read this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2)